# How can i make bold half of text in grid?

Tags: c#, xamarin, xamarin.forms, xamarin.android

I have some text in grid. I need make half of it bold and other half should be normal. How can i make it? For example ;

```
gr.Children.Add(new Label
                        {
                            
                            Text = $"Min. Adet : {data}",
                            TextColor = Color.FromHex("#22223b"),
                            FontSize = 16


                        }, 3, 3);
```

I need make bold = "Min. Adet : " , and "{data}" that one should be normal.  How can i make it ? Thanks for helps!!!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

use [Span](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/xamarin-forms/user-interface/text/label#formatted-text) and [FormattedText](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/xamarin-forms/user-interface/text/label#formatted-text)

```
    var layout = new StackLayout{ Padding = new Thickness (5, 10) };
    ...
    var formattedString = new FormattedString ();
    formattedString.Spans.Add (new Span{ Text = "Red bold, ", ForegroundColor = Color.Red, FontAttributes = FontAttributes.Bold });

    var span = new Span { Text = "default, " };
    span.GestureRecognizers.Add(new TapGestureRecognizer { Command = new Command(async () => await DisplayAlert("Tapped", "This is a tapped Span.", "OK")) });
    formattedString.Spans.Add(span);
    formattedString.Spans.Add (new Span { Text = "italic small.", FontAttributes = FontAttributes.Italic, FontSize =  Device.GetNamedSize(NamedSize.Small, typeof(Label)) });

    layout.Children.Add (new Label { FormattedText = formattedString });
    this.Content = layout;
```